# Continuity counterexamples for probability measures

Tags: probability, measure-theory, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples

I'm given a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ and a finitely additive measure $m$ that satisfies $m(\Omega) = 1$. I'm asked to give counterexamples for continuity from above and below.

My attempt (discontinuity from above): take $\Omega = \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ the set of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Define:
$$
m(A) = \begin{cases}
   0, & A \text{ finite} \\
   1, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Now, take $A_n = \{ j \in \mathbb{N} \ |\ j \geq n \} $ which satisfies
$$
A_1 \supset A_2 \supset \dots, \quad \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i = \emptyset \quad (A_n \downarrow \emptyset)
$$
Then, it obviously holds
\begin{align*}
  m\left(\bigcap_i^{\infty} A_i\right) &= m(\emptyset) = 0  \\
  \lim_{n \to \infty} m(A_n) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} m\left( \{ j \geq n, j \in \mathbb{N} \} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 = 1 \neq
  m\left( \bigcap_i^{\infty} A_i \right)
\end{align*}
since, $\forall n \geq 1$, $A_n$ is a co-finite set. Is my approach correct?

Comment: 1. Probability is mathematics.

2. Your example is close. If all the finite sets have 0 measure, there is a collection of sets that must have positive measure. You can't do this on the power set, for the reasons @Changlele set out.

Comment: @user24142: Would making $\mathcal{F}$ the set of all finite or cofinite sets work?

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima I feel like most people saying that are bitter and resentful for being perfect victims of bullying and as a consequence take pride in being useless.

Comment: @Sisyphus I am not allowed to delete my incorrect answer from smartphone. I am sorry for that.

Comment: @VHarisop what do you think? Prove it or disprove it. It definitely doesn't fall fowl of the existing counter example. But first - prove that the measure is  finitely additive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Actually, your finite additive measure $m$ is not well defined.

For example: by additivity $m(3n+1)+m(3n+2) = m(3n+1\cup3n+2)$ which imply $1+1 = 1$ which is false.